# How to stop R Markdown from converting LaTeX to odt/word formulae?

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I use R Markdown to write some statistical analysis reports that then need to be modified in LibreOffice (or Word). I use a library (`papaja`) that is extremely useful but forces me to use LaTeX that Pandoc then converts to formulae. I don't want it to be converted. The only thing I want to preserve form LaTeX formatting is italic for letters. That's exactly what I get when I use `rtf_document` as my output format – LaTeX letters are converted to italic, numbers to regular text. Is there a way to stop Pandoc from converting LaTeX to formulae when using `odt_document` or `word_document` as output? A work-around is to use `rtf_document` and then convert it to .odt with LibreOffice.

Example:

```
---
output: odt_document
---
The model fits the data ($F(3, 596) = 13.19$, $p < .001$).
```

What I get:
[image]
What I want to get:
[image]

Comment: Any luck in figuring this out?